# custom validation method and rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a custom validation method that uses a regexp to match on a users input and then throw an error if it fails.

Im trying to understand why the following scenario passes but the second example throws

```
undefined method match
```

Example 1 (Passes)

```
# Custom Validation
def format_mobile
 regexp = "/^(07[\d]{9})$/"
  if !(mobile_no.match(regexp))
   errors[:base] << "Please check your Mobile Number"
  end
end

# rspec test
it 'is invalid with an Invalid mobile number (Company)' do
 user = FactoryGirl.build(:user, company_form: true, mobile_no: '078055031888')
 user.format_mobile
 expect(user.errors[:base]).to include("Please check your Mobile Number")
end
```

Example 2 (Throws Error)

```
# Custom Validation
def format_mobile
 regexp = "/^(07[\d]{9})$/"
  if !(mobile_no.match(regexp))
   errors[:base] << "Please check your Mobile Number"
  end
end

# rspec test
it 'is invalid with a nil mobile number (Company)' do
 user = FactoryGirl.build(:user, company_form: true, mobile_no: nil)
 user.format_mobile
 expect(user.errors[:base]).to include("Please check your Mobile Number")
end
```

Any pointers as to why the second fails would be greatly appreciated, and how would i get that test to pass

thanks

EDIT

so this will pass a test if say the mobile_no 07805362669 was provided

```
def format_mobile
 regexp = /^(07[\d]{9})/
  if !(regexp.match(mobile_no))
   errors[:base] << "Please check your Mobile Number"
  end
end
```

but the tests where mobile_no is nil still fail

looking at the params if no mobile_no has no input it is passed as  "mobile_no"=>"", this is still nil though isnt it ?

Comment: As a side question, you asked 'looking at the params if no mobile_no has no input it is passed as "mobile_no"=>"", this is still nil though isnt it ?'  No, empty string is not nil. However, you are right that empty string does not match the regexp, so I am puzzled as to why japed's answer does not work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[nil](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/NilClass.html) is a nil class in ruby and doesn't have a match method.

[String](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-match) does have a match method.

As does [regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-i-match) where you pass the string to the regexp.  So simply call it the other way around

```
if !(regexp.match(mobile_no))
  #do_whatever
end
```

Comment: As itsnikolay points out you have made your regexp a string by encasing it in quote marks.

Comment: seems like your answer is correct (makes sense when i think about it) think theres an issue with my regexp, tests pass if i provide a 12 digit number, but fail if i provide a 10, i would like it to fail with 10 aswell

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your issue 
I've removed `"`, `"` and `$` 
Now it should pass

```
def format_mobile
 regexp = /^(07[\d]{9})/
  unless mobile_no.match(regexp)
   errors[:base] << "Please check your Mobile Number"
  end
end
```

rspec:

```
let(:user) { build :user, mobile_no: '07000000000' }
it 'validates mobile number' do
  expect(user.valid?).to be_falsey
  expect(user.errors).to include 'format errror message'
end
```

Full implementation of the validation with regexp
https://gist.github.com/itsNikolay/7bc0b946770da4bf039a

but much better the validation implement with

```
validates :mobile_no, presence: true, format: { 
  with: /^(07[\d]{9})/,
  message: 'shoud be in US format'
}
```

Comment: thanks...updated with my syntax error, but still getting same behaviour

Comment: thanks, i had to do this though to make it work unless regexp.match(mobile_no)... i removed "" and $ aswell.. but in the instances where mobile_no is nil, how would i get that to pass? add extra condition in my method ?

Comment: @Richlewis i've attached git implementation of the validation

Comment: @Richlewis allow user no provide a mobile number? or mobile number should present always ?

Comment: a user should always provide a mobile_no, so i would like to test for two things 1) that the format of the mobile number matches regexp and 2) and that the mobile_no is not left blank

Comment: @Richlewis i've updated my last code listing to adding `presence: true`

Comment: thanks for your help, think its solved now, issue with my regexp

Comment: @Richlewis but why you didn't mark my answer as right? =)

Comment: because @japed answer is correct, it was the way i was comparing the regexp

Comment: @Richlewis but i did your solution make to work, and with sorter syntax