# Check for nil value custom method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a custom method that checks a value against a regexp, but I would also like to check for a nil value but I'm not sure if I am checking both instances in the first clause. I need two different error messages depending upon whether it's nil or just doesn't match:

```
def format_mobile
 regexp = /^(07[\d]{9})$/
  if !(regexp.match(mobile_no))
   errors[:base] << "Please check your Mobile Number"
 elsif mobile_no.blank? // also tried mobile_no == nil
  errors[:base] << "Please provide your Mobile Number"
 end
end
```

Rspec tests

Passes

```
 it 'is invalid with a Invalid mobile number (Company)' do
  user = FactoryGirl.build(:user, company_form: true, mobile_no: '0780')
  user.format_mobile
  expect(user.errors[:base]).to include("Please check your Mobile Number")
end
```

Fails

```
it 'is invalid with a NIL mobile number (Company)' do
 user = FactoryGirl.build(:user, company_form: true, mobile_no: :nil)
 user.format_mobile
 expect(user.errors[:base]).to include("Please provide your Mobile Number")
end
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction with my custom method please?

Comment: How it differs from this http://stackoverflow.com/q/26237973/3297613 ?

Comment: because i  thought the solution was in those answers but upon further testing they don't seem to work

Comment: then ask it to the answerers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your order of checks. `nil` will not match the regexp, that’s why you never get into second `elsif`. Simply change the order:

```
def format_mobile
 regexp = /^(07[\d]{9})$/
 if mobile_no.blank? # also tried mobile_no == nil
   errors[:base] << "Please provide your Mobile Number"
 elsif !(regexp.match(mobile_no))
   errors[:base] << "Please check your Mobile Number"
 end
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: amazing, thank you, just tested this in the console and it works :-)  i seem to be getting thrown by nil values